# MFMailComposeViewController loads after delay if the "setToRecipients" method is called

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using MFMailComposeViewController and if I setup the recipients(setToRecipients), I can see 1-2 seconds delay between presenting the controller and the moment the data is loaded (at first an empty controller is presented, then the subject, body and recipients are loaded). It also causes that the navbar appearance settings is reloaded (tintColor).. It is noticeable only on simulator, but on device it happens as well, only it's faster so I can see the reloaded navbar settings.

Code:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    // content
    [mailer setSubject:self.mailSubject];
    [mailer setMessageBody:self.mailBody isHTML:NO];
    [mailer setToRecipients:@[@"asdf@asdf.com"]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    });

}
```

Comment: 1) keep a strong reference to mailer until last delegate method. 2) put all the code in the block even the mailer creation. The first is important or you will get crashes - the second may help your problem.

Comment: Hi @DavidH,
1) I'm keeping strong refference (I'm presenting the viewcontroller so my parent controller has strong referrence to it)
2) I'll try that

Comment: I just answered another devs problem with infrequent crashes with this object. Trust me, keep a strong reference (ivar) until last delegate message, then use a block on main thread to release it. Just search on 'MFMailComposeViewController' and you will see it (he gave me the answer and an uproot, as have a half dozen other people over past few years).

Comment: Did you find what was causing the delay? I'm facing the same issue and I think the delay is caused by the line `[mailer setToRecipients:@[@"asdf@asdf.com"]];`

Comment: @Rani Yes, that's exactly what is causing the delay, but I don't know why and I didn't find a solution.